# Php <= "valor" e >= "valor"?

Tags: php, lógica

Gostaria de saber como faço para o PHP detectar se uma variável esta com o valor entre um dos valores passados.

Explicando melhor tenho uma variável com um valor, este valor fara com que inclua um arquivo no conteúdo e eu preciso que o PHP detecte se estes valor é maior ou igual a "valor" e menor ou igual a "valor".

```
<?php 
$var = "valor>";

if ( $var <= "100") 
     include "m3.html";
else{
     if ( $var <= "40" && >= "99") 
          include "m1.html";
     else{
         if ( $var >= "39")
              include "m2.html";
    }
}
?>
```

Como vocês podem ver o segundo `if` que tem dois valores maior igual a *valor* e menor igual a *valor* tem me dado problema, já coloquei `&`, `&&` e `and` e não dá certo preciso que o PHP detecte se uma variável tem um valor entre *40* e *99* para incluir *m1.html*.

Comment: Estás a usar strings! Tens de usar numeros, senao ele vai comparar quantos caracteres tem em vez do valor numérico...

Comment: No caso o valor da var é numero tipo a var é um java script no 1° e 3° if da certo se retirar o 2° if agora quando tento verificar se o valor está entre 40 e 99 da erro, queria saber como colocar para verificar se este var está entre 40 e 99... @Sergio

Comment: Em vez de `$var <= "100"` tens de tirar as aspas e ter `$var <= 100`. Faz sentido a diferênça?

Comment: Faz, mais o pior é que enquanto temos dois valor <= e => da errado. Mesmo se tirar as aspas 
Este trecho código da erro             if ( $var <= "40" && >= "99")

Comment: Não dá para ser `a <= b` e  `b => c` ao mesmo tempo. Ou seja dá, mas é só um caso, quando `a == c`.

Comment: Será que não tem nada que verifique se var esta entre estes valores???

Comment: Podes fazer uma tabela com os casos que queres/tens? assim podemos ajudar mais na lógica e código...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo seu código sempre vai ficar no primeiro `if` porque pra chegar no `else` ele teria que ser maior que 100, e as operações dentro do `else` são todas menores do que 100, entendeu?

Primeiro você deve rever sua lógica. O terceiro `if` por exemplo te limita apenas se a variável for igual a 39, se não cai no segundo if, que por sinal está com erro, e a correção seria:

```
if ( $var >= 40 && $var <= 99 )
```

Se tiver dificuldade com a lógica, poste ela.

Comment: Veja bem, da forma como pensou parece dar certo, mas não é possível fazer assim. O PHP é interpretado no servidor, e o JS no navegador, então ele vai ser interpretado depois do PHP. Para você passar um parâmetro do JS para PHP você precisará dar um reload na página e recuperar o valor via $_GET no PHP. Você pode usar `window.location.repalce("suapagina.php?numero=" + wi);` Depois você recupera o numero no PHP: `$var = $_GET["numero"];`

Comment: Entendi e Desculpa ai não aprendi ainda a dar este fundo cinza no código em comentários

Comment: Sim @qmechanik é isso mesmo eu puxo o valor do <script> var wi = screen.width;</script> assim depois no php quero retornar para um html especifico de acordo com a resolução

Comment: Só fazendo uma correção em meu comentário: O código javascript seria: `window.location.replace("suapagina.php?numero=" + wi);` tinha um pequeno erro, pq fiz direto aqui :)

Comment: Será que tem como passar por $_POST no PHP afinal tenho que executar está função umas 2 ou 3 vezes na mesma pagina

Comment: Esse tipo de coisa não acho que seria legal passar por $_POST porque caso o usuário atualizasse a página ia ficar pedindo confirmação. Mas o que você poderia fazer e é bem comum seria fazer o cálculo direto no javascript e passar o nome da página pelo $_GET, dessa forma a url não ficaria estranha por assim dizer. Sua url ficaria como se fosse: suapagina.php?page=m3. Você pode personalizar o nome e tratar no php se quiser, aí fica a seu critério.

Comment: Vlw deu certo criei uma pagina que pega o valor e daí joga para todas as divs ! Facilitou muito minha vida.

Answer (score 2):

No segundo `if` há um erro de sintaxe `$var <= "40" && >= "99"` deve ser `$var >= "40" && $var <= "99"`.

```
<?php 
$var = "valor";
$varInt = (int)$var;  // Faz um cast para inteiro

if ($varInt <= 100) { // Tem certeza que isto aqui está certo? Não seria >= 100? 
   include "m3.html";
}
elseif ( $varInt >= 40 && $varInt <= 99) { // Se for 40 ou maior, e menor ou igual a 99 
   include "m1.html";
}
elseif ($varInt <= 39) { // Se for menor ou igual a 39. No teu código está >= 39
   include "m2.html";
}
else {
    // Fazer algo aqui caso tudo acima não seja executado
}
?>
```